# try to fill a table cell in word with python

Tags: python, docx, cpu-word

I'm learning to write on the word with python.
When I try to fill a table cell, not all of the paragraph is fetched..
for exemple nam.get() is not taken and It does not appear in the word file, while the rest appears

```
import docx
import os
os.getcwd()

doc = docx.Document('document_RS.docx')


table_inf=doc.add_table(rows =5, cols=1)
table_inf.cell(0,0).text = "Nom & prénom : "+ var_age.get() 
table_inf.cell(1,0).text = str(var_nom.get())

doc.save("new2.docx")
```

Comment: where are you getting the var_age.get() and the other, you made a tkinter GUI? put the code of the GUI too to see what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I made this and it works perfectly fine

```
import docx
import os
import tkinter as tk

def write_table():
    os.getcwd()

    doc = docx.Document()
    # doc.save("doc.docx")

    table_inf=doc.add_table(rows =5, cols=1)
    table_inf.cell(0,0).text = age.get()
    table_inf.cell(1,0).text = name.get()

    doc.save("new2.docx")
    os.startfile("new2.docx")

root = tk.Tk()
age = tk.Entry(root)
age.pack()
name = tk.Entry(root)
name.pack()

but = tk.Button(root,
    text="click to send data to table",
    command=write_table)
but.pack()
root.mainloop()
```